# Smart search and replace

Tags: awk, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I had some code that had a few thousands lines of code that contain pieces like this

```
opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom(0x1234, 1).toInt()
```

that I needed to convert to some other library that uses syntax like this

```
ReadFromOD<int>(0x1234, 1)
```

.

Basically I need to search for
`[whatever1]opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom([whatever2]).toInt()[whatever3]`
across all the lines of a text file and to replace every occurence of it with
`[whatever1]ReadFromOD<int>([whatever2])[whatever3]`
and then do the same for a few other data types.

Doing that manually was going to be a few days of absolutely terrible dumb  work but all the automatic functions of any editor I know of do not allow for any smart code refactoring tools.

Now I have solved the problem using GNU AWK with the script below

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    spl1 = "opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom("
    spl2 = ").to"
    spl2_1 = ").toString()"
    spl2_2 = ").toUInt()"
    spl2_3 = ").toInt()"
    min_spl2_len = length(spl2_3)

    repl_start = "ReadFromOD<"
    repl_mid1 = "QString"
    repl_mid2 = "uint"
    repl_mid3 = "int"
    repl_end = ">("
    repl_after = ")"
}

function replacer(str)
{
    pos1 = index(str, spl1)
    pos2 = index(str, spl2)
    if (!pos1 || !pos2) {
        return str
    }

    strbegin = substr(str, 0, pos1-1)
    mid_start_pos = pos1+length(spl1)

    strkey = substr(str, pos2, min_spl2_len)
    key1 = substr(spl2_1, 0, min_spl2_len)
    key2 = substr(spl2_2, 0, min_spl2_len)
    key3 = substr(spl2_3, 0, min_spl2_len)

    strmid = substr(str, mid_start_pos, pos2-mid_start_pos)
    if (strkey == key1) {
        repl_mid = repl_mid1; spl2_fact = spl2_1;
    } else if (strkey == key2) {
        repl_mid = repl_mid2; spl2_fact = spl2_2;
    } else if (strkey == key3) {
        repl_mid = repl_mid3; spl2_fact = spl2_3;
    } else {
        print "ERROR!!! Found", spl1, "but not any of", spl2_1, spl2_1, spl2_3 "!" > "/dev/stderr"
        exit EXIT_FAILURE
    }
    str_remainder = substr(str, pos2+length(spl2_fact))
    return strbegin repl_start repl_mid repl_end strmid repl_after str_remainder
}

{
    resultstr = $0
    do {
        resultstr = replacer(resultstr)
        more_spl = index(resultstr, spl1) || index(resultstr, spl2)
    } while (more_spl)
    print(resultstr)
}
```

and everything works fine but the thing still bugs me somewhat. My solution still feels a bit too complicated for a job that must be very common and must have an easy standard solution that I just dont't know about for some reason.

I am prepared to just let it go but if you know a more elegant and quick one-liner solution or some specific tool for the smart code modification problem then I would definitely would like to know.

Comment: Please add multiple lines of sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: A line may look like this: `power1 = opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom(0x1234, 1).toInt() * opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom(0x5678, 1).toUInt() * FACTOR1`, I need `power1 = ReadFromOD<int>(0x1234, 1) * ReadFromOD<uint>(0x5678, 1) * FACTOR1`. All the lines are pretty similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sed` is an option, you can try this solution which should match both output examples from input such as this.

```
$ cat input_file
opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom(0x1234, 1).toInt()

power1 = opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom(0x1234, 1).toInt() * opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom(0x5678, 1).toUInt() * FACTOR1;
power2 = opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom(0x5678, 1).toUInt() / 2;
```

```
$ sed -E 's/ReadDataFrom/ReadFromOD<int>/g;s/int/uint/2;s/(.*= )?[^>]*>([^\.]*)[^\*|/]*?(\*|\/.{2,})?[^\.]*?[^>]*?>?([^\.]*)?[^\*]*?(.*)?/\1\2 \3 \4 \5/' input_file
ReadFromOD<int>(0x1234, 1)

power1 = ReadFromOD<int>(0x1234, 1) * ReadFromOD<uint>(0x5678, 1) * FACTOR1;
power2 = ReadFromOD<int>(0x5678, 1) / 2;
```

- Explanation

`s/ReadDataFrom/ReadFromOD<int>/g` - The first part of the command does a simple global substitution substituting all occurances of `ReadDataFrom` to `ReadFromOD<int>`

`s/int/uint/2` - The second part will only substitute the second occurance of `int` to `uint` if there is one

`s/(.*= )?[^>]*>([^\.]*)[^\*|/]*?(\*|\/.{2,})?[^\.]*?[^>]*?>?([^\.]*)?[^\*]*?(.*)?/\1\2 \3 \4 \5/` - The third part utilizes `sed` grouping and back referencing.

- `(.*= )?` - Group one returned with back reference `\1` captures everything up to an `=` character, `?` makes it conditional meaning it does not have to exist for the remaining grouping to match.
- `[^>]*>` - This is an excluded match as it is not within parenthesis `()`. It matches everything continuing from the space after the `=` character up to the `>`, a literal `>` is then included to exclude that also. This is not conditional and must match.
- `([^\.]*)` - Continuing from the excluded match, this will continue to match everything up to the first `.` and can be returned with back reference `\2`. This is not conditional and must match.
- `[^\*|/]*?` - This is an excluded match and will match everything up to the literal `*` or `|` to `/`. It is conditional `?` so does not have to match.
- `(\*|\/.{2,})?` - Continuing from the excluded match, this will continue to match everything up to and including `*` or `|` `/` followed by at least 2 or more`{2,}` characters. It can be returned with back reference `\3` and is conditional `?`
- `[^\.]*?[^>]*?>?` - Conditional excluded matches. Match everything up to a literal `.`, then everything up to `>` and include `>`
- `([^\.]*)?` - Conditional group matching up to a full stop `.`. It can be returned with back reference `\4`.
- `[^\*]*?` - Excluded. Continue matching up to `*`
- `(.*)?` - Everything else after the final `*` should be grouped and returned with back reference `\5` if it exist `?`

Comment: `sed` is definitely an option and your example almost does what I need. It correctly converts `power1 = opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom(0x1234, 1).toInt() * opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom(0x5678, 1).toUInt() * FACTOR1;` into `power1 = ReadFromOD<int>(0x1234, 1) * ReadFromOD<uint>(0x5678, 1) * FACTOR1;` but it converts something like `power2 = opencanmanager.GetObjectDict()->ReadDataFrom(0x5678, 1).toUInt() / 2;` into `power2 = ReadFromOD<int>(0x5678, 1)` which is incorrect - it must be `power2 = ReadFromOD<uint>(0x5678, 1) / 2`.

Comment: Also now I just have to find out what all the round and square braced woodoo magic is... But thanks anyway.

Comment: @mrKirushko Give me a few minutes to look into this and provide a short explanation as to what the regex is doing